# Uploading presigned url to S3 with Jquery

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, upload, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload a file to s3 according to the instructions here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python

but the xhr request fails due to CORS. My CORS settings on the bucket are as permissive as possible:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

So I tried uploading via ajax instead:

```
var postData = new FormData();
    for (key in s3Data.fields) {
        postData.append(key, s3Data.fields[key]);
    }
    postData.append('file', file);
    console.log(postData);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: url,
        contentType: file.type,
        processData: false,
        data: postData
    })
```

and this works, but only if I unblock all public access.

Is there a way to get this to work with public access blocked and using presigned urls?